# I have opened 'install.sh' file to install Kyocera printer, but don't know how to 'Run'

Tags: printing

I need help installing my printer.

I put the 'tar-gz' file in a new folder and opened it, clicked on 'tar.gz', and the files were 'install.sh', the different '.ppds,' and 'rastertokpsl.'

The instructions say 'Run' when the 'install.sh' file opens, but I don't know how to do this.

I clicked install.sh and it says
says the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d /usr/share/cups/model ]; then
 sudo mkdir /usr/share/cups/model
fi
if [ ! -d /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera ]; then
sudo mkdir /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera
fi
sudo cp Kyocera_FS-1041GDI.ppd /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1041GDI.ppd
sudo cp Kyocera_FS-1220MFPGDI.ppd /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1220MFPGDI.ppd
sudo cp Kyocera_FS-1320MFPGDI.ppd /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1320MFPGDI.ppd
sudo cp Kyocera_FS-1325MFPGDI.ppd /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1325MFPGDI.ppd
sudo cp Kyocera_FS-1061DNGDI.ppd /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1061DNGDI.ppd 
sudo cp rastertokpsl /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl
if [ -f /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl ] && [ -f /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1041GDI.ppd ] && [ -f /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1061DNGDI.ppd ] && [ -f /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1220MFPGDI.ppd ] && [ -f /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1320MFPGDI.ppd ] && [ -f /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1325MFPGDI.ppd ]; then
echo "Installation completed"
else
echo "Installation failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to DIY (using `sudo` in scripts is a bad idea and that one may ask for your password 8 times) you can just open a terminal (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) then `cd` to the directory that contains the files (you can navigate to it and click "open in terminal" if you're not sure how to do this) and enter the commands from the script to do the same thing

make a directory for the `.ppd` files:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera
```

copy the files to the right places:

```
sudo cp *.ppd /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera
sudo cp rastertokpsl /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl
```

And that's the installation done, according to the script